# Stopping NSURL Connection before redirect, while getting the redirect URL

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am trying to get back the response body of a url, which redirects to another invalid url. I would like to stop the redirection as well, since it crashes my app.

I have tried using the following methods within my code, but they aren't picked up:

```
func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
    dataTask dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask,
    didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse,
    completionHandler completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        print("Did you get here?")
}

func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
    task task: NSURLSessionTask,
    didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        print("How about here?")
}

func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
    task task: NSURLSessionTask,
    willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse,
    newRequest request: NSURLRequest,
    completionHandler completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?) -> Void) {
        print("Maybe here?")
}

func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
    didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?) {
        print("Did you find an error?")
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do?

EDIT: So, this is the updates code that I have that gives me no errors using XCode 7:

```
class Example: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {


override init() {
    super.init()

    let mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    // Put your handler as the second parameter.
    let data = try!mySession.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!, completionHandler: myHandler)

    data!.resume()
}

// Create your handler with the following signature, and read the response body.
func myHandler(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void {

    // In this case the “encoding” is NSASCIIStringEnconding. It depends on the website.
    let responseBody = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

    print(responseBody)
}



// Handles redirection
private func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {

    // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
    completionHandler(nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

To stop a redirect and get the response body you should call the `completionHandler` with `nil` as the parameter.

After you stop the redirect, URLSession will call the handler you specified, when you created a HTTP Get request with `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`(could also be `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:`). Then in the handler you get the responde body. Example:

```
import Foundation

class Example: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {


    override init() {
        super.init()

        let mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

        // Put your handler as the second parameter.
        let data = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!, completionHandler: myHandler)

        data.resume()
    }

    // Create your handler with the following signature, and read the response body.
    func myHandler(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void {

        // In this case the “encoding” is NSASCIIStringEnconding. It depends on the website.
        let responseBody = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        println(responseBody)
    }



    // Handles redirection
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {

        // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```

Apple Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:

I know it works with the HTTP 302 code, but for others like 301 (Moved Permanently) or 308 I don't know if it works.

Worth adding (about `URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:`):

> This method is called only for tasks in default and ephemeral sessions. Tasks in background sessions automatically follow redirects.

Comment: I had to change the method URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:), as it was giving me errors and now it does not like that the completionHandler has a nil argument.

Comment: What errors was it giving? I've just tested the code above with XCode 6.4 and iOS 8.4, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I am using XCode 7, and I get: `cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, completionHandler: (NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void)'`, as well as `Objective-C method 'URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:' provided by method 'URLSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'URLSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)' in protocol 'NSURLSessionTaskDelegate'`

Comment: I can get rid of the second error, by making the function private.

Comment: Well, all I can think of is: is the file a swift file? Do you have two `URLSession(:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)` functions in the same class?

Comment: I changed some of the syntax and I now have no errors. I however, don't think I am initializing my request right, because it doesn't seem to reach that code.

Comment: Can you confirm if the function `URLSession(:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)` is called? Implement `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` as well, see if it tells us something.

Comment: Hi, it works. I can get back the response body for http://www.google.com, but for my link, it gets to the function and then just crashes.

Comment: In what function it crashes? See what status code you get back in `willPerformHTTPRedirection` by doing: `response.statusCode`

Comment: @pkc456 It's been a while since I've programmed in Swift, so I don't know how It would be in Swift 3. If someone more familiar with it could update the code, I would appreciate the help

Comment: For people wondering about it, note than if you use nil as parameter for the willPerformHTTPRedirection completionHandler, you can use the completionHandler of the dataTaskWithURL method.